Why did Abraham not know who Isaac should marry if G-d told him?
At the end of Parshat Vayera (22:20), Abraham is informed that his brother Nahor has fathered a number of descendants, including a granddaughter named Rebecca.
Rashi ad loc (20) explains that these verses were to reassure Abraham that Isaac's spouse had been born, and on the verse "and Bethuel begot Rebecca" (23) Rashi makes it clear that the entire genealogical transcription was on account of this verse.
(Also note that Rebecca is the only female mentioned in the entire passage.)
With that in mind, why wasn't it obvious to Abraham who Isaac's soulmate was destined to be? why didn't he send Eliezer with explicit instructions?
Someone suggested to me that the message was conveyed to Abraham via non-divine methods, so it wasn't a prophesied announcement.
But that sort of begs the question, what was the point of informing Abraham then?

Even though one may think that G-d had preordained that Rivka was Yitzchak's soulmate, the choice to marry was in her and Yitzchak's hands. For example, Avraham states so to Eliezer in Bereshis 24:8

And if the woman does not consent to follow you, you shall then be clear of this oath to me; but do not take my son back there.”

which Rashi explains:

THEN SHALT THOU BE CLEAR FROM THIS MY OATH etc. — and take a wife for him from the daughters of Aner or Eshcol or Mamre.

The point is also repeated in Bereshis 24:49:

And now, if you mean to treat my master with true kindness, tell me; and if not, tell me also, that I may turn right or left.”

which Rashi explains:

TO THE RIGHT HAND — to take a wife of the daughters of Ishmael. TO THE LEFT — to take a wife of the daughters of Lot who dwelt at the left of Abraham (Genesis Rabbah 60:9).

Perhaps, due to passing the Akkeida test by Yitzchak, Avraham was told about Rivka as the best available offer for his son Yitzchak. It is implied by the comment of Sforno to Bereshis 22:23 (Thanks Rabbi Kaii!)

ובתואל ילד את רבקה, the person relating all this to Avraham added that Bethuel, a son of Nachor’s proper wife, sired Rivkah. The meaning of the message was that there had been born in his own family a girl who would be a suitable wife for Avraham’s son so that he would not have to look for such a wife among the K'naanites surrounding him.

That's why Avraham tells Eliezer that Rivka was coming fully from his family, while all other candidates were not. Aner, Eshcol, and Mamre were K'naanim; Yishmael had a mother and a wife from Mitzraim; children of Lot, Ammon and Moav, also took wives from the women of K'naan. Finally, Eliezer's daughter was not from Avraham's family as Eliezer was Eved K'naani, originally from K'naan (some other opinions are known too).

So does this disprove the concept of soul mates?

@ddas91600 there is no shoresh זוג in Tanach, i.e. it is likely a post-talmudic concept.

Interesting... but in that case, what was the point of telling Abraham about Rebecca then?

@Chani perhaps, due to passing the Akkeida test by Yitzchak, it was a note of the best available offer for him.

@YDJ זוג is lashon chazal, the concept of soul mates is in the gemara in several places, including Moed Katan 18b, and Sotah 2a (where the word זיווג is used)

@YDJ this Sforno implies that Avraham didn't have specific information about who was the zivug, although he knew Rebecca was a candidate: https://www.sefaria.org/Sforno%20on%20Genesis%2022:20:1

@RabbiKaii Thank you. I am adding this point.

In addition to Y DJ's answer, there are a couple more possibilities.

Avraham may have known, but he didn't want to interfere with Hashem's hashgacha, as is implied by this Malbim:


שכ"ז נעשה בהשגחתו, הוא ישלח מלאכו שליח ההשגחה שהיא תבא אל יצחק
Since all of this was done under His providence, He will send His
angel, the agent of divine oversight, to find a wife for Isaac.

Speculation: It could be that Avraham was trying to show how important it is to rely on Hashem completely and totally, and giving Eliezer too much information would prevent that. It could also be that this is support for the concept that a soul mate is not necessarily fixed and can change based on deeds etc.

He did hint that it should be Rivka to Eliezer, according to Radak:


ואל מולדתי, העיר שנולדתי והיא אור כשדים; ר"ל כי שם ימצא משפחתו, ועל
רבקה רמז לו כי הוגד לו שנולדה. ובב"ר א"ר יצחק. כי אל ארצי היינו דאמרי
אינשי חטין דקרתך זונין מנהון זרע:
ואל מולדתי, the town in which I was born, i.e. Ur Kasdim. Avraham
meant to say that there Eliezer would find his family; he hinted at
Rivkah, seeing that he had been informed of her birth. According to
Rabbi Yitzchok in Bereshit Rabbah 59,8 the words “to my land” reflect
a well known proverb according to which people prefer to plant seed
originating in their own backyard even though the strain is known to
be inferior to those available elsewhere [R Eli Munk translation]

Speculation: It could be that Avraham wanted to show how loyal and trustworthy Eliezer was, so he only gave him a hint.

In most midrashim it says hashem told him that his zivug was born but Hashem didnt tell him who it was. It could rashi also means this, hes just saying to us who it was, but not that hashem told Avraham the name.

If all Abraham heard was that Isaac's soulmate had been born, why does the Torah tell US about Rebecca then? Like a spoiler?

@Chani  and why does torah say everyone else that was born? And yea, its like a spoiler
